# How to change XML attributes to elements then move them to different node?

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to convert the attributes of `<Card>` elements (`id`, `status`, `type`) to child elements of the associated `<Information>` element.  I have implemented the attribute -> element change, but how can I give the resulting elements the correct parent?

Here is a sample input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Customers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" hasMore="false"
    recordCount="1" responseTime="2017-04-27T19:35:02" returnCode="SUCCESS">
<Customer>
<Information>
<FirstName>Brandon</FirstName>
<MiddleName/>
<LastName>Wrong</LastName>
<CustomerStatus>ACTIVE</CustomerStatus>
<Household>false</Household>
<EnrollmentDate xsi:nil="true"/>
<Address>100 Broadway Ave</Address>
<City>San Gabriel</City>
<State>CA</State>
<ZIP>91776-2348</ZIP>
<Country/>
<Phone>6268881212</Phone>
<MobilePhone/>
<Email>BWrong1@gmail.com</Email>
<DateOfBirth xsi:nil="true"/>
</Information>
<Cards>
<Card id="40012345601" status="ACTIVE" type="Customer card"/>
</Cards>
</Customer>
</Customers>
```

And here is my current stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                >

  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Customers/@hasMore|Customers/@recordCount|Customers/@returnCode|@xsi:nil|@responseTime" />

    <xsl:template match="Card/@*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="comment() | text() | processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you put the job to be done in terms of moving nodes around, you're thinking in an unhelpful way.  XSL doesn't *change* (or *move* or etc.) anything.  Rather, it defines a result document in terms of the characteristics of input documents.

Since part of defining an element of the output document is defining its content, it follows that an output element's child nodes must be defined in the context of the template for that output node.  For your particular case, then, you need a template tailored more specifically to your `<Information>` elements than identity transform you are using now.

Before we continue with the specifics, however, I observe as an aside that the identity transform you define, spread as it is over three separate templates and explicitly using only elements' and attributes local names, is more verbose than the canonical identity transform for no apparent reason or advantage.  Here's the usual identity transform, all in one template:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

You seem, however, to be suppressing all attributes other than namespace declarations and the ones that you are transforming to elements.  In that case, instead of providing a template that explicitly suppresses attributes, how about just avoiding transforming them in the first place, by using (only) this variation on the identity transform instead:

```
<xsl:template match="node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <!-- transform child nodes, except attributes -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

You do not need special provision for preserving namespace declarations with this approach, as `xsl:copy` automatically copies the copied node's namespace nodes, resulting in namespace declarations being provided were needed.

With that out of the way, the wanted template for `<Information>` elements can be written as a variation on the identity template:

```
<xsl:template match="Information">
  <xsl:copy>
    <!-- transform all the element's child nodes -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    <!-- include also transformations of the associated <Card> attributes -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="../Cards/Card/@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The template you already have for the `<Card>` attributes will probably do, though it's unclear why you're using `local-name()` instead of `name()`.  It does seem, however, that you probably want to avoid emitting seemingly informationless `<Cards>` and `<Card>` elements into the output document.  You can do that by providing a template for `<Cards>` that transforms it to nothing:

```
<xsl:template match="Cards"/>
```

Putting that all together, then, you might arrive at something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8"
              omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <!-- attributes are not matched or selected for transformation by this
       template: -->
  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Information elements require a special template: -->
  <xsl:template match="Information">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- transform all the element's child nodes -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      <!-- include also transformations of the associated <Card> attributes -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../Cards/Card/@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- transform <Cards> elements to nothing -->
  <xsl:template match="Cards"/>

  <!-- applied only where matching attribute nodes are selected for
       transformation: -->
  <xsl:template match="Card/@*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi John, Thank you for correcting my stylesheet.  You are very knowledgeable of XSLT.   As a newby, I am learning how to program xsl as part of my programming development.  I really appreciate your answer and learned something from you.  I would like to understand more about XSL learning.  Would you mind pointing me to the right direction?  As a visual learner,I am looking searching for video clips to help me speed up the learning process.  If you know any good training materials, please share with me!

Comment: Hi John, Is it possible to get rid of the <customer> node to make it <Customers><Information>?  My application treats <customer> as another table...

Comment: @Brandon168, I don't do recommendations for off-site resources, which are off-topic here.  And it sounds like the kind of resource you are looking for is different from the kind I would be inclined to recommend, anyway.  Google is your friend; it will turn up all manner of resources for you.

Comment: @Brandon168, as for omitting the `<Customer>` element, sure, it's possible.  Provide a template for that element that does nothing but apply templates to its children -- i.e. one that does not copy the node itself.

Comment: How can I change the xsl you provided to not copy the node itself if I want the end result of the XML like below which eliminate <customer> node but keep the <Information> node?